# monotonic function is riemann-integrable?

Tags: integration

$f$ is a real-valued monotonic function on $[a,b]$ and $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing on $[a,b]$.

Then my professor said $$\int_{a}^{b}f\,\mathrm{d}\alpha $$does not always exist, but I can't find example.

Comment: Take $\;\alpha(x)=x\;,\;\;f\;$ your favourite non Riemann integrable function....

Comment: but f is monotonic

Comment: If $f$ is monotonic, it is continuous $\lambda^1$-a.e. and therefore Riemann integrable. So I don't think you can pick a non-integrable $f$.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal Not if $\;f\;$ isn't bounded, say...

Comment: i found answer at another site. f=alpha=0(x<c), f=alpha=1(x>=c) then U-L=1 so not integrable